# Ошибка 502 Bad Gateway nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть приложение, которое по запросу пользователя открывает в новом окне некий текст. Пробовала его запускать на одном сервере (на нем стоит только `Apache`), все проходит нормально, текст выгружается. При попытке запустить его на другом (стоит связка `nginx + Apache`) выходит ошибка `502 Bad Gateway`.

В логах значится, что она выходит из-за этого `WSARecv() failed (10054: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение)`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем она может быть вызвана? что `nginx` так не нравится???

Лог `nginx`:

> 2016/02/18 12:12:39 [debug] 9380#8020: select event: fd:364 wr:0
>   2016/02/18 12:12:39 [debug] 9380#8020: select timer: 500
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: select ready 1
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: select read 364
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 post event 00910CB0
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: timer delta: 453
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: posted event 00910CB0
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 delete posted event 00910CB0
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 http upstream request:   "/site/config/get_text.php?prescript_id=755"
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 http upstream process header
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 malloc: 00962008:4096
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [debug] 9380#8020: *222 WSARecv: fd:364 rc:-1 0 of 4096
>   2016/02/18 12:12:40 [error] 9380#8020: *222 WSARecv() failed (10054: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение) while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.113.60.113, server: server_name.ru, request: "GET /site/config/get_text.php?prescript_id=755 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/site/config/get_text.php?prescript_id=755", host: "server_name.ru", referrer: "http://server_name.ru/site/site.php"

Настройки `nginx`:

```
worker_processes  1;  
error_log  logs/error.log;  
events {  
    worker_connections  1024;  
}  

http {  
    include       mime.types;  
    default_type  application/octet-stream;  
    #17.02.2016  
    client_max_body_size 10m;  
    client_body_timeout 6m;  
    client_header_timeout 6m;  
    send_timeout 6m;  
    sendfile        on;  
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    server {  
        listen       10.0.0.4:80;  
        server_name  server_name.ru;  

        #charset koi8-r;  
        location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {  
            root c:/vhost/server_name.ru.ru/web;  
            index index.php;  
        }  

        location / {  
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;  
            proxy_read_timeout 600;  
            #17.02.2016  
            proxy_send_timeout 600;  
            #17.02.2016  
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;  
            proxy_set_header Host $host;  
        }  

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;  
        location = /50x.html {  
            root   html;  
        }  
}
```

Comment: Смотрите еще на настройки nginx, возможно у Вас значения proxy_send_timeout, proxy_read_timeout, proxy_buffer_size, large_client_header_buffers, client_max_body_size очень маленькие

Answer (score 2):

1. Пересмотрите логи `nginx` и скиньте сюда;
2. Убедитесь, что правильно перенаправляете с `nginx` на `apache`  запросы (на порт `8080`). Пересмотрите, на каком порте работает `apache` и `nginx`, может быть с настройками что то не так. Вот пример конфига для `nginx`:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name host_name *.host_name;  
       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_connect_timeout 120;
           proxy_send_timeout 120;
           proxy_read_timeout 180;
       }   
   }
   ```
3. Если ничего не получится, попробуйте поменять настройки `apache`, чтобы он работал на `80` порту, но перед этим отключите `nginx`. Может быть сам `apache` не работает или настройки не правильные. Пример конфига на `apache`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
       ServerAdmin postmaster@host_name
       ServerName host_name
       ServerAlias *.cool.local
       DocumentRoot "/var/www/host_name/"
       ErrorLog "logs/cool_local.log"

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. **Не забудьте при каждом изменении в настройках перезапустить `apache` и `nginx`!**